# how to expose ingress for Consul

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, consul

I'm trying to add consul ingress to my project, and I'm using this GitHub repo as a doc for ui and ingress: [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-helm/blob/497ebbf3cf875b028006a0453d6232df50897d42/values.yaml#L610) and as you can see unfortunately there is no ingress in doc, there is an ingressGateways which is not useful because doesn't create ingress inside Kubernetes(it can just expose URL to outside)

I have searched a lot, there are 2 possible options:

1: create extra deployment for ingress

2: create consul helm chart to add ingress deploy

(unfortunately I couldn't find a proper solution for this on the Internet)

Comment: You'll have to write your own ingress object in yaml. The exact solution depends on which ingress controller you're using. For traefik, there's a clue here: https://github.com/KnowledgeHut-AWS/vault-on-k8s/blob/refactored/platform/secrets/ingress.yaml.todo but, it's unfinished.

Comment: yes, but its not for consul @SoftwareEngineer

Comment: For general Kubernetes Ingresses, you'll have to follow what @SoftwareEngineer recommended. However, after the briefest of searches, it looks like Consul breaks the mold a bit, and use a Kubernetes Service with CRDS. Maybe [this](https://developer.hashicorp.com/consul/tutorials/get-started-kubernetes/kubernetes-gs-ingress) will help with Option #1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example Docker compose file which configures Traefik to expose an entrypoint named `web` which listens on TCP port 8000, and integrates Traefik with Consul's service catalog for endpoint discovery.

```yaml
# docker-compose.yaml
---
version: "3.8"
services:
  consul:
    image: consul:1.8.4
    ports:
      - "8500:8500/tcp"
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.3.1
    ports:
      - "8000:8000/tcp"
    environment:
      TRAEFIK_PROVIDERS_CONSULCATALOG_CACHE: 'true'
      TRAEFIK_PROVIDERS_CONSULCATALOG_STALE: 'true'
      TRAEFIK_PROVIDERS_CONSULCATALOG_ENDPOINT_ADDRESS: http://consul:8500
      TRAEFIK_PROVIDERS_CONSULCATALOG_EXPOSEDBYDEFAULT: 'false'
      TRAEFIK_ENTRYPOINTS_web: 'true'
      TRAEFIK_ENTRYPOINTS_web_ADDRESS: ":8000"
```

Below is a Consul service registration file which registers an application named `web` which is listening on port 80. The service registration includes a couple tags which instructs Traefik to expose traffic to the service (`traefik.enable=true`) over the entrypoint named `web`, and creates the associated routing config for the service.

```
service {
  name = "web"
  port = 80
  tags = [
    "traefik.enable=true",
    "traefik.http.routers.web.entrypoints=web",
    "traefik.http.routers.web.rule=Host(`example.com`) && PathPrefix(`/myapp`)"
  ]
}
```

This can be registered into Consul using the CLI (`consul service register web.hcl`). Traefik will then discover this via the catalog integration, and configure itself based on the routing config specified in the tags.

HTTP requests received by Traefik on port 8000 with an `Host` header of `example.com` and path of `/myapp` will be routed to the `web` service that was registered with Consul.

Example curl command.

```sh
curl --header "Host: example.com" http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp
```

This is a relatively basic example that is suitable for dev/test. You will need to define additional Traefik config parameters if you are deploying into a production Consul environment which is typically secured by access control lists (ACLs).

Answer (score 1):

The [`ingressGateways`](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-helm/blob/v0.25.0/values.yaml#L1205) config in the Helm chart is for deploying a Consul [ingress gateway](https://www.consul.io/docs/connect/gateways/ingress-gateway) (powered by Envoy) for Consul service mesh. This is different from a Kubernetes Ingress.

Consul's ingress enables routing to applications running inside the service mesh, and is configured using an [ingress-gateway](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/config-entries/ingress-gateway) configuration entry (or in the future using [Consul CRDs](https://www.consul.io/docs/k8s/crds)). It cannot route to endpoints that exist outside the service mesh, such as Consul's API/UI endpoints.

If you need a generic ingress that can route to applications outside the mesh, I recommend using a solution such as Ambassador, Traefik, or Gloo. All three of this also support integrations with Consul for service discovery, or service mesh.

Comment: thanks for your explanation, yes I should use Traefik as a controller, the problem is for these kind of tasks I always follow the documentation in Github/hashicorp website, but unfortunately there is no template/example about this target

Comment: Check out this guide for running Traefik with HashiCorp Nomad https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/nomad/load-balancing-traefik. It should be straightforward to adapt the config to docker-compose or similar. I have an example I can share, but unfortunately it won't fit into the comments.